# Common Uses For Pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm a programming student with two classes in C#, but I'm just taking my first class in C++, and thus I'm being exposed to pointers.

I know how they work, and the proper way to use them, but I wondered about some of the ways that  professional programmers use pointers in their programs.

So how do you use pointers? Or do you?

This will help me understand some practical applications for pointers, so thanks!

Comment: Look at this one to see why pointers are sometimes used for parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/2139254#2139254

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Any time you'd use a reference in C#. A "reference" is just a pointer with fancy safety airbags around it.

I use pointers about once every six lines in the C++ code that I write. Off the top of my head, these are the most common uses:

- When I need to dynamically create an object whose lifetime exceeds the scope in which it was created.
- When I need to allocate an object whose size is unknown at compile time.
- When I need to transfer ownership of an object from one thing to another without actually copying it (like in a linked list/heap/whatever of really big, expensive structs)
- When I need to refer to the same object from two different places.
- When I need to slice an array without copying it.
- When I need to write directly to a specific region of memory (because it has memory-mapped IO).

Comment: "When I need to refer to the same object from two different places." For that one, a reference is often better.

Comment: You can't reseat a reference. I meant cases where I have objects A, B, X, and Y, all in different scopes. X and Y both need to refer to A.  Later on, without creating a new X and Y, I must make them both refer to B. If X and Y both contain a `Foo &A`, then I can't reseat it to B. I could have some kind of fancy handle class that has a .Reseat() function, but internally it would use a pointer anyway.

Comment: "You can't reseat a reference." Of course you can't. But that's not needed every time you need to refer to the same object from two different places. (See function parameters, for example.)

Comment: Would be great to see a little example for each case you are referencing, please.

Answer (score 6):

For staters, you use them in your [data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure), like linked list, etc.  Anyplace you need dynamically allocated memory, that is, memory that you don't know the size of at compile-time, you will be using a [pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computing)).

Answer (score 1):

If you have some time on your hands for reading a book, I would recommend reading [*The C Programming Language*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) which makes heavy use of pointers.

A simple example of a standard function:

```
/* strlen: return length of string s */
int strlen(char *s) {
    char *p = s;
    while (*p != '\0') p++;
    return p - s;
}
```

Comment: And why would anyone use that in actual **C++** code (except when writing a string class)?

Comment: They might need to compute the length of a string.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: please don't recommend *The C Programming Language* and C-style for someone who starts a C++ course.

Comment: Good point. I do recommend it if you really want to understand how to use pointers though

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1 of 2**

Pointers are often required to interface with C libraries when data needs to be passed into an existing API.  This mechanism is not limited to "legacy" systems, modern examples include OpenGL, DirectX, and Win32.

below is an example from OpenGL:
glVertexPointer(int,float,int,float*) takes a float pointer as the first argument.

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {...}; // 24 of vertex coords
...
// activate and specify pointer to vertex array
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

// draw a cube
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);

// deactivate vertex arrays after drawing
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

instead of using an statically defined array it would be ok to do the following:

```
Glfloat *vertex = new GlFloat[24];
...
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
...
delete [] vertex.
```

or if you want to use std::vector

```
std::vector<Glfloat> vertex;
vertex.resize(24);
...
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertices[0]);
...
```

---

**Part 2 of 2**

Pointers to objects and function pointers are useful in defining static member function that needs to operate on a specific instance of a class.  This idiom appears in callback mechanisms.

```
class foo {
  ...
  public:
    static int s_callback0(void* obj){
      return (foo*)(obj)->callback0();
    } 
    int callback0(){
      ...
    }
    ...
};

class callbackAPI {
  public:
    int setCallback(int(*fn)(void*),void* context){
      m_fn(fn);
      m_context(context);
    }
    void run (){
      m_fn(m_context);
    }
  private:
    int(*m_fn)(void*);
    void *m_context;
};

main {
  foo f;
  callbackAPI cb;
  cb.setCallback(foo::s_callback0,f);
  cb.run();
}
```

If you have control of callbackAPI similar results could be achieved with inheritance and templates.  The above examples demonstrates a way of working with a callbackAPI provided by a 3rd party when required to provide a function pointer.