# Initialize stringstream reference member in constructor initialization list with nothing

Tags: c++, reference, constructor, initialization-list

I tried to init a stringstream reference member with nothing, saying I wanted it to refer to null or just leave it un-initialized.

.hpp file

```
class Class{
    private:
        int n;
        stringstream& css;
    public:
        Class(int n);
        Class(stringstream& ss, int i);
    };
```

.cpp file

```
Class::Class(int n)
    :   n(n)    
{}
```

The compiler gives: 
Error   1   error C2758: 'Class::css' : must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list

Do I have to initialize all the variables in the initialization list?
Because I am not passing any stringstream reference to the constructor, how do I initialize it? Or if I don't want to initialize it, leave it blank. How do I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References members *must* be initialized.  You don't want a reference, you want a pointer.

```
class Class{
private:
    int n;
    stringstream* css;
public:
    Class(int n);
    Class(stringstream& ss, int i);
};

Class::Class(int n)
    :n(n), css(nullptr)    
{}

Class::Class(stringstream& ss, int i)
    :n(i), css(&ss)
{}
```

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: No, smart pointers are for ownership.  This is a nullable reference.  That's the one function left for which raw pointers are still useful.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: If you make it a shared_ptr, you put a demand on your user that they must be using a shared_ptr too.  They might just want to give you a reference to a local, non-dynamically allocated object.

Comment: But then don't you run the risk of remaining with a dangling pointer?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Sure. You just have to treat the class like you would any reference or pointer.  If you want an added measure of security, make it non-copyable.

Comment: I see. So a nullable reference member is a valid use-case for a raw pointer. Do you know of any further reading I can do on this?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: No, I don't.  It's just a conclusion I came to a couple of years ago.  I answered a question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029970/c-what-are-scenarios-where-using-pointers-is-a-good-ideatm/4029988#4029988), and had it confirmed by a few other StackOverflowers whos opinion I respect.